# Cannot store multiple radio button values in php and mysql

Tags: html, mysql, radio-button

I want to store radio button values for each question to my database. I ran it and it stores only for the first question. I know that it may be wrong using `if` and `elseif`. The user answers in all questions how can I store them all in mysql table? Does it need to use `for` loop?

```
  saveunit.php
  <?php

  include'connect.php';


  if(isset($_POST['u1'])){
    $u1 = $_POST['u1'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO unit_form (u1) VALUES ('$u1')");
}
  elseif(isset($_POST['u2'])){
    $u2 = $_POST['u2'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO unit_form (u2) VALUES ('$u2')");
}

 ?>


unitform.php

<form action="saveunit.php" method="POST">

U1 I have found the unit intellectually interesting and stimulating :  <br />
1 <input type="radio" name="u1" value="1">  2 <input type="radio" name="u1" value="2">  3 <input type="radio" name="number" value="u1">  4 <input type="radio" name="u1" value="4">  5 <input type="radio" name="u1" value="5"> <br /> <br />

U2 I have gained knowledge that I consider valuable :  <br />
1 <input type="radio" name="u2" value="1">  2 <input type="radio" name="u2" value="2">  3 <input type="radio" name="u2" value="3">  4 <input type="radio" name="u2" value="u2">  5 <input type="radio" name="u2" value="5"> <br /> <br />

U3 I have acquired skills and abilities that I consider valuable :  <br />
1 <input type="radio" name="u3" value="1">  2 <input type="radio" name="u3" value="2">  3 <input type="radio" name="u3" value="3">  4 <input type="radio" name="u3" value="4">  5 <input type="radio" name="u3" value="5"> <br /> <br />


<input type = "Submit" name = "Submit1" value = "Submit">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">
```

Comment: It does not make sense to use `elseif` in the php part of the code. `u1` is probably always set, so there is no way you will every come to evaluate `u2` like that. Just use a normal `if()` instead, the same for `u3`...

Comment: Oh, and a side note: your code is vulnerable to sql injection. That is a serious security risk for your system. You have to fix that, no excuse. Stop using the deprecated `mysql` extension, start using the more modern `mylsqi` extension or `PDO` and read about the advantages of "prepared statements" for that.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you need an if and an else if. It stores the u1 because it always execute the first if(), that's why it always store the first data  . What you need to do is to have all the units in one if().
Try this...

```
 if(isset($_POST['u1'])){
    $u1 = $_POST['u1'];
    $u2 = $_POST['u2'];
    $u3 = $_POST['u3'];
    $u4 = $_POST['u4'];
    $u5 = $_POST['u5'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO unit_form (u1,u2,u3,u4,u5) VALUES ('$u1','$u2','$u3','$u4','$u5')");
}
```